# Unsubscibe Paypal Button

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have been trying to Integrate a Unsubscribe Button. But i have not been able to do this properly.

After CLINET clicks the Unsubscribe button, it asks the Merchant to Login. This should not happen. It should just ask for a confirmation of cancellation.

I have tried making a custom Button via Sandbox. All testing has been done and still no success. The parameters for this Unscubsribe button is not available.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, have a look at [Using the Button Creation Tool for an Unsubscribe Button](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/#id08ADFH00MX8).